# Can't Lock NFT after Delegating using Metaplex

Tags: blockchain, web3js, solana, metaplex

According to metaplex docs here : https://developers.metaplex.com/token-metadata/delegates, I first use the approve function to select a delegated authority. The function works as expected and here I can see that https://explorer.solana.com/tx/2rc14gbRE11jT6uJrpf6SzL2wBcFaaaetjXEJPQMMZLJB6dWqkoXYMAbrp5sh3KKkYRqKu1Gcr7ET67yG1o1SSUz?cluster=devnet, delegate authority is now of my choice account with publickey : 5nsp1dfFFxoneGKEhSgaUvFiHDFtTqSBc3bUBqTedh8r

When I connect to my d'app using the delegated authority wallet(5nsp1dfFFxoneGKEhSgaUvFiHDFtTqSBc3bUBqTedh8r) and try to execute the lock function, I get an incorrect account error. But as I mentioned above I can see that the delegated authority is correct in Solana Explorer.

What am I missing here ?

Any answer would be very appreciated, thanks!